# Python3 - filter text before writing to a file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, filtering

This is a function that is called by my main.py script.

Here is the issue, I have a file with a list of IP addresses, and I query this API in order to find me reverse DNS lookups of those given IPs against the (url) variable. Then spits out the "response.text".

Well in the response.text file,

I get No DNS A records found for 96.x.x.x

Other data I get is just a dnsname: 'subdomain.domain.com'

How do I filter my results to NOT show for every 'No DNS A records found for (whateverip shows)'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import pdb
#function to use hackertarget api for reverse dns lookup
def dns_finder(file_of_ips="endpointslist"):
    print('\n\n########## Finding DNS Names ##########\n')
    targets = open("TARGETS","w")
    with open (file_of_ips) as f:
        for line in f:
            line.strip()
            url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=' + line
            response = requests.get(url)
            #pdb.set_trace()
            hits = response.text
            print(hits)
            targets.write(hits)
            return hits
```

Comment: I edited my answer a bunch, but it should help you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module to check the response to make sure it is a valid DNS hostname (using a regular expression pattern):

```
import re

# ... rest of your code

# before writing to targets file
if re.match('^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$', hits) is not None:
    targets.write(hits)
```

The `re.match()` function will return a match object if the given string matches the regex. Otherwise, it will return `None`. So if you check to make sure it is not `None`, then it should have matched the regex (i.e. it matches the pattern for a DNS hostname). You could alter the regex or abstract the check to a more generic `isValidHit(hit)` and put any functionality you want there to check for more than just DNS hostnames.

### Note

You want to be careful with your line `targets = open("TARGETS","w")`. That opens the file for writing, but you need to manually close the file elsewhere and handle any errors involved with IO to it.

You should try to use `with open(filename) as blah:` whenever dealing with file IO. It is much safer and easier to maintain.

### Edit

Simple regex for IPv4 address found [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html).

Add more explanation of the regex `match` function.

### Edit 2

I just re-read your post and saw that you are actually not looking for IPv4 addresses, but actually DNS hostnames...

In that case you could simply switch the regex pattern to `^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$`. [Source for the DNS Hostname regex](https://www.regextester.com/23).

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Klein answer is great if you want to keep only the domain names. Howerver, as stated in the question, if you just want to remove error messages like "No DNS A records found for ...", then you can use the `str.startswith` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import pdb
#function to use hackertarget api for reverse dns lookup
def dns_finder(file_of_ips="endpointslist"):
    print('\n\n########## Finding DNS Names ##########\n')
    targets = open("TARGETS","w")
    with open (file_of_ips) as f:
        for line in f:
            line.strip()
            url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/reverseiplookup/?q=' + line
            response = requests.get(url)
            #pdb.set_trace()
            hits = response.text
            print(hits)
            if not hits.startswith("No DNS A records found for"):
                targets.write(hits)
            return hits # why iterating if you return there ?
```